# SwiftUI Picker in reusable component with protocol cannot conform to Hashable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swift-protocols

I'm trying to build a reusable component that includes a SwiftUI Picker that can work with different types in several places in my app. I created a Pickable protocol that conforms to Hashable, but when I try to use it, the Picker and the ForEach complain that Type 'any Pickable' cannot conform to 'Hashable'

```
import SwiftUI

struct PickerRow: View {
    let title: String
    let options: [any Pickable]
    @State var selection: any Pickable
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Text(title)
                .font(.subHeading)
            Picker(title, selection: $selection, content: {
                ForEach(options, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0.name)
                }
            }).pickerStyle(.menu)
        }
    }
}

protocol Pickable: Hashable {
    var name: String { get }
}
```

Is there a way to get something like this to work without specifying a concrete type?

Comment: SwiftUI wrappers/views require concrete types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think about it, it makes sense.

What would you expect to happen if that code was valid and you used it like this?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let options = [PickableA(), PickableB()]
    @State var selection = PickableC()
    var body: some View {
        PickerRow(title: "Choose one", options: options, selection: $selection)
    }
}
```

That couldn't possibly work right?

What you need is a way to make sure that there is a constraint that forces `options` and `selection` to be of the same concrete type (consider `Equatable` for example, both `String` and `Int` are conforming, but you cannot compare them).

One possible solution would be a generic constraint in the declaration of your struct (also note the `@Binding` instead of `@State` since we modify external values):

```
struct PickerRow<Option: Pickable>: View {
    let title: String
    let options: [Option]
    @Binding var selection: Option
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Text(title)
                .font(.subheadline)
            Picker(title, selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(options, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0.name)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(.menu)
        }
    }
}
```

which you could use like this:

```
struct Person: Pickable {
    let name: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let options = [Person(name: "Bob"), Person(name: "Alice")]
    @State var selection = Person(name: "Bob")
    var body: some View {
        PickerRow(title: "Choose one", options: options, selection: $selection)
    }
}
```